# Closure Compiler no longer able to determine type

Tags: google-closure-compiler

I've been using Google's Closure Compiler for most of my projects, and a few of them in advanced mode with 100% typed.

One of my projects though no longer gets stated as 100% typed and I get warnings for things that I didn't used to get them for, and I can't seem to be able to figure out why. This is the message I get

```
WARNING - could not determine the type of this expression
                                                v['children'].map(v => new _ChildLineItem(v['child'], v['option'], v['quantity'], v['price'])))))),
                                                                                                                                  ^
```

There's 42 more warnings like it, all about the same code, which I have here

```
    /**
     * @constructor
     * @param {Array<!_Quote>} quotes
     * @param {string} email
     * @param {?string} quoteid
     */
    function _GetQuotes(quotes, email, quoteid) {
        this.quotes = quotes;
        this.email = email;
        this.quoteid = quoteid;
    }

    /**
     * @constructor
     * @param {string} quoteid
     * @param {boolean} shipping
     * @param {Array<!_Proof>} proofs
     * @param {Array<!_LineItem>} lineitems
     */
    function _Quote(quoteid, shipping, proofs, lineitems) {
        this.quoteid = quoteid;
        this.shipping = shipping;
        this.proofs = proofs;
        this.lineitems = lineitems;
    }

    /**
     * @constructor
     * @param {string} number
     * @param {string} main
     * @param {string} thumbnail
     */
    function _Proof(number, main, thumbnail) {
        this.number = number;
        this.main = main;
        this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
    }

    /**
     * @constructor
     * @param {string} name
     * @param {number} quantity
     * @param {number} price
     * @param {Array<!_ChildLineItem>} children
     * */
    function _LineItem(name, quantity, price, children) {
        this.name = name;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.price = price;
        this.children = children;
    }

    /**
     * @constructor
     * @param {string} child
     * @param {string} option
     * @param {number} quantity
     * @param {number} price
     * */
    function _ChildLineItem(child, option, quantity, price) {
        this.child = child;
        this.option = option;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.price = price;
    }

    Ajax({
        url: '/ajax/getquotes',
        data: Data,
        success: function (/** !_GetQuotes */ data) {
            var d = new _GetQuotes(
                data['quotes'].map(v => new _Quote(v['quoteid'], v['shipping'],
                    v['proofs'].map(v => new _Proof(v['number'], v['main'], v['thumbnail'])),
                    v['lineitems'].map(v => new _LineItem(v['name'], v['quantity'], v['price'],
                        v['children'].map(v => new _ChildLineItem(v['child'], v['option'], v['quantity'], v['price'])))))),
                data['email'], data['quoteid']);
    ...
```

I can rewrite the closures to specify the types of the objects coming through like this

```
v['children'].map(function( /** !_ChildLineItem */ v) { new _ChildLineItem(v['child'], v['option'], v['quantity'], v['price'])}
```

But shouldn't it be able to figure that out from the constructor definitions?

---

Actually me specifying all of them like this isn't even working

```
var d = new _GetQuotes(
    data['quotes'].map((/** !_Quote */ v) => new _Quote(v['quoteid'], v['shipping'],
        v['proofs'].map((/** !_Proof */ v) => new _Proof(v['number'], v['main'], v['thumbnail'])),
        v['lineitems'].map((/** !_LineItem */ v) => new _LineItem(v['name'], v['quantity'], v['price'],
            v['children'].map((/** !_ChildLineItem */ v) => new _ChildLineItem(v['child'], v['option'], v['quantity'], v['price'])))))),
    data['email'], data['quoteid']);
```

With this warning

```
WARNING - could not determine the type of this expression
                                                v['children'].map((/** !_ChildLineItem */ v) => new _ChildLineItem(v['child'], v['option'], v['quantity'], v['price'])))))),
                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Well, I wouldn't really have thought twice about it until you said you were getting errors.  Vaguely disturbed by the associative array - does CC assume that the typing of the non-numerically indexed properties in an Array might not be the declared type? Wondering if v[5].map... would generate the same warning.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is that the compiler generally treats computed and dot property accesses differently.  Computed property accesses are treated as the 'unknown' type unless you give a type signature the [] operator (i.e. the class implements IArrayLike as Array does or IObject[2] for map like objects).

Although, the compiler could understand that x.foo and x['foo'] are reference the same property, it does not currently do this.

[1] https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Special-types-in-the-Closure-Type-System